# Applying a fn to all the dataframe value not just a column without using .apply

Tags: python, apply, higher-order-functions

Assume element -> 0D, column or row -> 1D, matrix -> 2D

`applymap` maps a function elementwise in dataframe, `apply` maps a function columnwise

Is there any other way applying a fn *dataframewise* (or i would say *matrix wise*)
or even in tensor wise where our data is in higher dimension like 7D

Thanks in advance :D